# How do I change the version of Python being used in my RMakrdown code chunks?

Tags: python, r-markdown, chunks

I apologise first as I am very new to much of this.

I am working in Markdown and I want to use the python package tweepy. Now this requires a more updated version of Python than my current one:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

which gives me

```
2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]
```

Because I get

```
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

when I try to import it.

So I have downloaded Python version 2.7.14 to my laptop, and I find it as a folder in Applications ( I am on a Mac using OS X 10.11.6 ).

This has updated the Python used when I open terminal, but the code chunks still use the old version. I am unsure of how to save this version of Python to a different location. I feel like what I need to do is change the engine.path parameter in the code chunk, but I am not sure how I move this version of Python and refer to it in the engine.path.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Best wishes

B

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when using knitr and RMarkdown. You need to set the `engine.path` variable in your chunk. If you are using Anaconda, it might look like this...

````
```{python, engine.path="~/anaconda3/bin/python"}
your code here...
```
````

If you open `python` in your terminal and run...

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

It should point you to the location of the python executable you should pass as an argument to `engine.path` in RMarkdown/knitr.